need to check frequency of voice from microphone in flutter
I am new to flutter I need to get frequency of voice from microphone, Below is code I used but didn't get any needful answer.
I used a package called fftea for fourier transformation in flutter.
I just want to get frequency continuously and show it in text view using setState.
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:fftea/impl.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Microphone Frequency Analyzer',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: AudioStreamPage(),
    );
  }
}

class AudioStreamPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AudioStreamPageState createState() => _AudioStreamPageState();
}

class _AudioStreamPageState extends State<AudioStreamPage> {
  static const stream = EventChannel('audio_stream');
  StreamSubscription? _streamSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _streamSubscription = stream.receiveBroadcastStream().listen((dynamic data) {
      // Process audio data here
      // This data will be the byte array from the microphone
      // You can send it to your analysis method
      analyzeAudioData(data);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _streamSubscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void analyzeAudioData(List<int> audioData) {
    // Implement frequency analysis here (e.g., FFT)
    // Calculate the dominant frequency or frequency range
    // Display the frequency information in the UI
    // This method will be called for each audio data chunk received
    // Implement your frequency analysis logic here

    List<int> myData = audioData;

    final fft = FFT(myData.length);
    final freq = fft.realFft(myData.cast<double>());
    print(freq);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Microphone Frequency Analyzer')),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Streaming audio data...'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Thanks in advance.

Is this an exercise? In which case, maybe check with the person that created it.
